# What does this R error message mean

Tags: r

I am trying to predict a value for certain variable on my model, together with 95% confidence interval and I keep getting the same error that one of my variables is not found.

Here is the code bit and error message I am getting:

```
pred.frame <- data.frame(lpsa=seq(min(prostate$lpsa), max(prostate$lpsa),
+ length=100))

pp <- predict(pros8.lm, int="p", newdata=pred.frame)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'lcavol' not found
```

I've created a data frame with all of my variable included, together with specific values I want to test, but from some reason it does not identify one of them.

Here is the created data frame:

```
newpatient <- data.frame(lcavol = 1.44692, lweight = 3.62301, age = 65.0,
lbph = 0.3001, svi = 0.0000, lcp = -0.79851,
gleason = 7.0, pgg45 = 15.0)
```

Can someone identify/point out why this does not work?

Comment: you might want consider changing the title of your question

Comment: Look at the colnames of `pred.frame`. There is no column 'lcavol' in it (as your error already told you)

Answer (score 0):

In `predict` you're specifying the newdata to use is `pred.frame`. But in `pred.frame`, there is no column `lcavol` (that your model `pros8.lm` needs to make a prediction.

You might want this:

```
    predict(pros8.lm, int="p", newdata=newpatient)
```